# how can i access a file/folder over network through XP_CMDSHELL in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, file-access, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to access a folder/directory using 'EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL' it works for the local file/folder, how ever it can not access the folder over network.

```
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL 'c:\Images'  --Works fine
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL '\\IPaddress\Images' -- returns "Access is denied."
```

Please note that i can access the network location but not using sql server.

Sql server is running under Winodws Authentication mode. 
Sql server is using 'nt authority\network service' account to access the remote Folder.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you run xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe' it will tell you the account the command is running under. If this account doesn't have permissions on the network, you'll get the error you are seeing.

Check the SQL documentation for changing this account/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to put file, like BCP result, or a backup in a remote drive, just map this drive into windows don't work, it must be mapped on SQL Server to!, to do this, try some link like this:

exec xp_cmdshell 'net use p:\ \Server\Folder\Folder\Folder\ /Domain\Login /Password'

Reference : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6eca2d62-eb86-4f23-9b86-6f917017f50c/bcp-utility-via-xpcmdshell-and-network-drive?forum=sqlsecurity